# Can I use a TV character name for my business brand?

Tags: copyright, dmca

"Species 8472" is a legendary race in the Star Trek universe, which is the only one other than humans to ever have defeated the Borg. It has particular resonance amongst tech nerds, for this reason.

I want to therefore register a website with the number 8472 in it. For example "trader8472" or "sensor8472" etc. Would this be against copyright? Assume I did not use the likenesses of Species 8472 nor any overt Star Trek references. Am I likely to have CBS or Paramount, owners of Star Trek, come after me if the site is operated as a business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no IP in a number - can't be copyright, can't be trademarked. We have Pentium chips today because Intel couldn't patent the 586.

Comment: I think you mean "couldn't *trademark* the 586". I am pretty sure there are plenty of patented features in it.

Comment: "So this number is,
once again, the player key:
(trade secret haiku?)

*** - ***; and then
*** *** *** -- *** times; then
*** *** (less ***)

*** *** *** ***; and last (of course not least)
the humble ***. "